# Swift MacOS getting bad json response from jsonSerialization

Tags: json, swift, string

I am trying to convert a string to JSON in Swift.

Here's the string, which I am getting by pulling the innerHTML from a WKWebView.

```
{"list":{"pagination":{"count":3,"hasMoreItems":false,"totalItems":3,"skipCount":0,"maxItems":100},"entries":[{"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-06-16T21:00:32.714+0000","isFolder":false,"isFile":true,"createdByUser":{"id":"UserFName.userLName@xxxxxxxx.com","displayName":"UserFName userLName"},"modifiedAt":"2020-06-16T21:00:32.714+0000","modifiedByUser":{"id":"UserFName.userLName@xxxxxxxx.com","displayName":"UserFName userLName"},"naxxxxxxxxme":"00-invest-2020-06-16-17-00-32-716.txt","id":"028b4c82-09b8-4ee5-b4fa-9696a33b026d","nodeType":"log:fileNode","content":{"mimeType":"text/plain","mimeTypeName":"Plain Text","sizeInBytes":609373,"encoding":"UTF-8"},"parentId":"ba647bfc-a889-4d91-9211-4220cfe7d90a"}},{"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-06-16T21:01:12.828+0000","isFolder":false,"isFile":true,"createdByUser":{"id":"UserFName.userLName@xxxxxxxx.com","displayName":"UserFName userLName"},"modifiedAt":"2020-06-16T21:01:12.828+0000","modifiedByUser":{"id":"UserFName.userLName@xxxxxxxx.com","displayName":"UserFName userLName"},"name":"00-monetize-2020-06-16-17-01-12-830.txt","id":"d6412e3a-fea5-4d4d-a962-d91cde294bc9","nodeType":"log:fileNode","content":{"mimeType":"text/plain","mimeTypeName":"Plain Text","sizeInBytes":996653,"encoding":"UTF-8"},"parentId":"ba647bfc-a889-4d91-9211-4220cfe7d90a"}},{"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-06-16T18:33:49.344+0000","isFolder":true,"isFile":false,"createdByUser":{"id":"UserFName.userLName@xxxxxxxx.com","displayName":"UserFName userLName"},"modifiedAt":"2020-06-16T18:34:49.211+0000","modifiedByUser":{"id":"UserFName.userLName@xxxxxxxx.com","displayName":"UserFName userLName"},"name":"20200616","id":"d881db96-ddcb-44ae-99e1-ffe3ac0c2810","nodeType":"cm:folder","parentId":"2fcf4c49-be4c-4f2c-a90b-654ae092c63e"}}]}}
```

I've checked the string in JSON Lint and it says it is valid.

Here's what I am doing in my code to convert it:

```
let strJSONLiteral = """
\(strJSON)
"""
                        
//convert string to json
let data = strJSONLiteral.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
      if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
      {
          print(myJSON) // use the json here
      } else {
          print("bad json")
      }
} catch let error as NSError {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The error is occurring in the JSONSerialization attempt. I'm getting nil for myJSON. Data check looked ok, has 1600+ bytes.

Comment: Did you try printing strJSONLiteral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level `JSON` is of type `Dictionary` while you're trying to decode an `Array` of `Dictionary`. To fix this
Replace:

```
if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
```

With:

```
if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any>
```

Or you can just use `[String: Any]`.

Add-on: You should probably do a bit of research on `Codable` and try to use it for these scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. It fixed it. Yeah, I know how to use Codable, right now we were just trying to get data in, this is an Alfresco API (content management) that requires a SAML login process. That was the stumbling block.

Comment: Welcome @Gazoo. Keep coding.